# trouble reading file in same script after print export via sys.stdout to the same file

Tags: python, stdout

I am utilizing an audio analysis script that outputs a bunch of print commands. After the print commands are all executed and exported to an external text file via sys.stdout in the script, I want to read the text file in the same script. However, the text file comes out empty within the script. I have tried running f.flush() and f.seek() which doesn't help. When I open the text file after the script has completed, the contents of all the print commands display as expected. It looks like the script has to complete in order for sys.stdout() to write the contents to the external file. Can I ensure that this step happens prior to the f.read() at the end of my script?

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
#print(sys.path)

import time

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

start_time = time.time()

import numba
import numpy as np
import librosa

def print_color(msg, color=32):
    if sys.stdout.isatty():
        print("\033[{color}m {msg} \033[0m".format(msg=msg, color=color))
    else:
        print(" *** {msg} ***".format(msg=msg))

# TODO: configure this via cmdline
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100 # Hz
ELF_THRESHOLD_DB = -22 #dB
#OLDBUCKET N_FFT = 16384
N_FFT = 13000
FIRST_BASS_BUCKET = 0
LAST_BASS_BUCKET = 11
LAST_ANALYSIS_BUCKET = 64
DEBUG_ENABLED = False

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("ElfTag: Extremely Low Frequency Audio Tagger")
    print("Usage: %(cmd)s </path/to/directory>" % {"cmd": sys.argv[0]})
    sys.exit(0)

#filename = sys.argv[1]
directory = sys.argv[1]
print(directory)
#filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
#filename = "/Volumes/SDXC128GB/ElfTag/sp/02. Luma.mp3"

def debug(msg):
    if DEBUG_ENABLED:
        print(msg)


files = librosa.util.find_files(directory)
print("Total Tracks: ",len(files))
queue = (len(files))

class Tee:
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.out1.write(*args, **kwargs)
        self.out2.write(*args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self, out1, out2):
        self.out1 = out1
        self.out2 = out2
    def flush(self):
        pass

import sys
logfile = input ("Enter Filename for Log File: ")
sys.stdout = Tee(open(logfile, "w"), sys.stdout)

for filename in files:
    try:
        queue = queue - 1
        print(queue, "Songs Remaining")
        print("Loading %(filename)s" % {"filename": filename})
        y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)
        duration = librosa.core.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr)
        print("Detected sample rate: %(sr)d Hz, duration: %(duration)f seconds." % {"sr": sr, "duration": duration})

        bin_size_hz = float(sr) / N_FFT
        num_bins = N_FFT / 2 + 1
        print("Using transform length of %(n_fft)d for FFT, which gives us %(num_bins)d bins at %(bin_size_hz)f Hz per bin." % {"n_fft": N_FFT, "num_bins": num_bins, "bin_size_hz": bin_size_hz})

        start_hz = bin_size_hz * FIRST_BASS_BUCKET
        end_hz = bin_size_hz * (LAST_BASS_BUCKET + 1)
        anal_hz = bin_size_hz * (LAST_ANALYSIS_BUCKET + 1)
        print("Detecting deep bass as peaks between %(start)f Hz and %(end)f Hz above %(db)d dB chosen from frequency range below %(anal)f Hz." % { "start" : start_hz, "end" : end_hz, "db" : ELF_THRESHOLD_DB, "anal" : anal_hz })

        #y = librosa.core.to_mono(y)
        D = librosa.stft(y, n_fft = N_FFT)

        tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr, units='frames', hop_length=512)
        numBeats = beats.shape[0]
        print("Estimated tempo: %(tempo)f." % {"tempo" : tempo})
        print("Number of beats detected: %(beats)d." % {"beats" : numBeats})

        # Split into Harmonic and Percussive layers to aid with beat detection
        #H, P = librosa.decompose.hpss(D)
        P = D
        P = librosa.amplitude_to_db(P, ref=np.max)

        totalFrames = P.shape[1]
        print("Total frames: %(frames)d, about %(secPerFrame)f seconds per frame" % {"frames": totalFrames, "secPerFrame": (duration / totalFrames)})

        # Select significant bass frame rows
        Pbass = P[FIRST_BASS_BUCKET:(LAST_ANALYSIS_BUCKET + 1)]

        firstFrame = np.argmax(Pbass.max(axis=0) > -80)
        debug("firstFrame")
        debug(firstFrame)

        Pbass = Pbass[:, firstFrame:]
        debug("Pbass")
        debug(Pbass)

        localmaxBass = librosa.util.localmax(Pbass)
        debug("localmaxBass")
        debug(localmaxBass)

        maskBass = localmaxBass[FIRST_BASS_BUCKET:(LAST_BASS_BUCKET + 1)]
        debug("maskBass")
        debug(maskBass)

        ourBass = Pbass[FIRST_BASS_BUCKET:(LAST_BASS_BUCKET + 1)]
        debug("ourBass")
        debug(ourBass)

        filteredBass = (ourBass > ELF_THRESHOLD_DB)
        debug("filteredBass")
        debug(filteredBass)

        peakFilteredBass = np.multiply(filteredBass, maskBass)
        debug("peakFilteredBass")
        debug(peakFilteredBass)

        vertBassFrames = np.sum(filteredBass, axis=0)
        debug("vertBassFrames")
        debug(vertBassFrames)

        horizBassFrames = (vertBassFrames > 0)
        debug("horizBassFrames")
        debug(horizBassFrames)

        deepBassFrames = np.nonzero(horizBassFrames)[0]
        debug("deepBassFrames")
        debug(deepBassFrames.shape)
        debug(deepBassFrames)

        # Adjacent Deep Bass detector

        shiftedHorizBassFrames = np.append(horizBassFrames[1:], [False])
        andedShiftedHorizBassFrames = np.logical_and(horizBassFrames, shiftedHorizBassFrames)
        adjacentHorizBassFrames = np.logical_and(andedShiftedHorizBassFrames, np.append(andedShiftedHorizBassFrames[1:], [False]))

        debug("adjacentHorizBassFrames")
        debug(adjacentHorizBassFrames)

        # /End Adjacent Deep Bass detector

        debug("beats")
        debug(beats.shape)
        debug(beats)

        deepBassBeats = np.intersect1d(deepBassFrames, beats, assume_unique=True)
        debug("deepBassBeats")
        debug(deepBassBeats.shape)
        debug(deepBassBeats)

        numDeepBeats = deepBassBeats.shape[0]
        print("Number of deep beats: %(numDeepBeats)d" % {"numDeepBeats": numDeepBeats})
        deepBeatsPercentage = float(numDeepBeats) / numBeats
        print("Percentage of deep beats: %(deepBeatsPercentage)f" % {"deepBeatsPercentage": deepBeatsPercentage})
        numBassFrames = horizBassFrames.sum()
        print("Number of frames with deep bass: %(frames)d." % {"frames": numBassFrames})
        numAdjacentBassFrames = adjacentHorizBassFrames.sum()
        print("Number of adjacent frames with deep bass: %(frames)d." % {"frames": numAdjacentBassFrames})
        bassFramesPerBeat = float(numBassFrames) / numBeats
        print("Number of deep bass frames per beat: %(bassFramesPerBeat)f" % {"bassFramesPerBeat": bassFramesPerBeat})
        bassFramesPercentage = float(numBassFrames) / totalFrames
        print("Percentage of deep bass frames: %(bassFramesPercentage)f" % {"bassFramesPercentage": bassFramesPercentage})
        adjacentBassFramesPercentage = float(numAdjacentBassFrames) / totalFrames
        print("Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: %(bassFramesPercentage)f" % {"bassFramesPercentage": adjacentBassFramesPercentage})
        #if %(bassFramesPercentage)f" % {"bassFramesPercentage": adjacentBassFramesPercentage} >= "0.30":
        #    print("DEEP BASS TRACK NEEDS TAGGING")
        print(("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)))
        #sys.exit(0)

    except:
        continue

f= open(logfile, 'r+')
f.flush()
f.seek(0)
fh = f.read()
print(fh.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not flushing the output file that you're writing to. Implement the `flush` method in your `Tee` class:

```
def flush(self):
    self.out1.flush()
    self.out2.flush()
```

Then use `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of your loop.

Comment: @MatthewStory I can't think of why. It's rarely used.